# Declared variable reads as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two variables `user` and `group` declared. When I run the function `removeGroupFromSite()`, it should alert me saying please select a group but the variable returns as **null**. I assume it's because it's getting the value of the select and not the selected option? How would I get the value of the selected option within these variables?

```
var user, group, strHTMLSiteUsers, strHTMLSiteGroups, strHTMLAvailable, strHTMLAssigned, arrOptionsAssigned, arrGroups, arrUsers, intOpts, booMatch, booErr;

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    user = $('#my_SiteUsers');
    group = $('#my_SiteGroups');
    groupsAssigned = $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned");
    groupAvailable = $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable");
    userAssigned = $("#my_SPUsersAssigned").html("");
    userAvailable = $("#my_SPUsersAvailable").html("");

    $("button").click(function() { return false; });

    populateUsers();
    populateGroups();
});

function removeGroupFromSite(){
  //check if default group selected 
  alert('cp'+group.val());
  if(group.val() !== "default"){
    var removeConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete group: " + group.val());
    if(removeConfirm){
      $().SPServices({
        operation:"RemoveGroup",
        groupName: group,
        async:true,
        completefunc: function (xData,Status){
            alert(group + " succesfully deleted");
        }
      });
    }
  }else{
    alert("Please select a group");
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="my_SiteGroups" style="width:200px;" onchange="RefreshUserLists()">
        <option value='default' disabled="disabled">Select a group</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: you must intialise `group = $('#my_SiteGroups');` inside the `removeGroupFromSite`

Comment: but if I have users = $('#my_SiteUsers')...wouldn't users.val() equal the same thing?

Comment: @diEcho isn't group a global variable? When I initialize it in the ready function, should it's value be carried anywhere within the script?

Comment: You can use  $('#my_SiteGroups').val()  or $('#my_SiteGroups option:selected').val()  to get the selected option value.

Comment: i dont think this statement would execute `group.val() !== "default"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple fix

remove `disabled="disabled"` from `<option>`

`disabled` property does not carry the value from **DOM** as it was disabled.

[`Reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

**disabled**

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not
>   available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be
>   dispatched on disabled controls. Also, a disabled control's value
>   isn't submitted with the form. This attribute is ignored if the value
>   of the type attribute is hidden.

Comment: whoa, did not know that